# How to install scp and ssh to Powershell?

Tags: powershell, posh-ssh

I installed Posh-SSH with: Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH

When trying to execute scp or ssh, I am getting something like below. Why?

```
scp : The term 'scp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ scp
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (scp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

**UPDATE**
With the help of @tommymaynard, I can see all the available commands:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $x = Find-Module -Name Posh-SSH
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $x.AdditionalMetadata.Functions -split ' '
Get-PoshSSHModVersion
Get-SFTPChildItem
Get-SFTPContent
Get-SFTPLocation
Get-SFTPPathAttribute
Get-SFTPSession
Get-SSHPortForward
Get-SSHSession
Get-SSHTrustedHost
Invoke-SSHCommand
Invoke-SSHCommandStream
Invoke-SSHStreamExpectAction
Invoke-SSHStreamExpectSecureAction
Invoke-SSHStreamShellCommand
Move-SFTPItem
New-SFTPFileStream
New-SFTPItem
New-SFTPSymlink
New-SSHDynamicPortForward
New-SSHLocalPortForward
New-SSHRemotePortForward
New-SSHShellStream
New-SSHTrustedHost
Remove-SFTPItem
Remove-SFTPSession
Remove-SSHSession
Remove-SSHTrustedHost
Rename-SFTPFile
Set-SFTPContent
Set-SFTPLocation
Set-SFTPPathAttribute
Start-SSHPortForward
Stop-SSHPortForward
Test-SFTPPath
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $x.AdditionalMetadata.Cmdlets -split ' '
Get-SCPFile
Get-SCPFolder
Get-SCPItem
Get-SFTPFile
Get-SFTPItem
New-SFTPSession
New-SSHSession
Set-SCPFile
Set-SCPFolder
Set-SCPItem
Set-SFTPFile
Set-SFTPFolder
Set-SFTPItem
```

From there, which command would you use to replace the 'scp' and 'ssh' below (ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_configuring-key-based-authentication)?

```
$REMOTEHOST="your-user-name-on-host@host-fqdn-or-ip-goes-here"

scp "$env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub" "${REMOTEHOST}:~/tmp.pub"
ssh "$REMOTEHOST" "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat ~/tmp.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && rm -f ~/tmp.pub"
```

Comment: Windows 10 comes with ssh and scp since 1809.

Answer (score 0):

The module you installed doesn't included a function/cmdlet named "scp." I didn't install the module, but did run the following commands to determine the names of the functions and cmdlets in the module.

```
$x = Find-Module -Name Posh-SSH
$x.AdditionalMetadata.Functions -split ' '
$x.AdditionalMetadata.Cmdlets -split ' '
```

**Edit**: Did you read the help for the *scp* commands? I did. One of those is bound to do what you need. I went ahead an installed the module on my computer and ran the following to quickly obtain the synopsis for the *scp* commands in this module.

```
Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH
Get-Command -Module Posh-SSH -Name *scp* |
ForEach-Object {"$($_.Name): $((Get-Help -Name $_).Synopsis)"}

Get-SCPFile: Download a File from a SSH Server using SCP
Get-SCPFolder: Download a folder from a SSH Server using SCP.
Get-SCPItem: Download from a remote server via SCP a file or directory.
Set-SCPFile: Copies a file to a SSH server using SCP.
Set-SCPFolder: Copies a folder to a SSH server using SCP.
Set-SCPItem: Upload an item, either file or directory to a remote system via SCP.
```

Comment: I updated my question with the results of your commands. What do you think I should do?